# Error loading the webpart '' of type ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, kentico

**Works Locally but doesnt work when deployed to dev, using same kentico configuration settings on local and dev. Changes on local apply straight to dev.**

So I am working on an existing project which is using Kentico. I have created a new web part and template and when trying to go the new page (web part) I receive this error.

Error loading the webpart '' of type ''

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
Inherits="CMSWebParts_General_ResetPassword" 
CodeBehind="~/CMSWebParts/General/ResetPassword.ascx.cs" %>

<div id="reset-password-page" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1 style="color: white; margin-top: 0px;">Reset Password</h1>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px; color: #eb770a!important; padding-left: 20px;" class="row">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <span style="color: red; position: relative; left: 12px;" id="validation"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:" CssClass="col-sm-3 control-label">Password:</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" Monitor="Monitor" data-rel="password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword2" runat="server" Text="Repeat Password:" CssClass="col-sm-3 control-label">Repeat Password:</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword2" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" Monitor="Monitor" data-rel="password"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10" id="reset">
                <asp:Button ID="ResetBtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn caseFileButton" Text="Reset" CausesValidation="True" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Here is the view essentially, however this is an old version of ASP - hence .ascx files.

This has been working, but very inconsistently, if there is any Kentico experts or ASP experts, some help would be appreciated.

I have a code behind file created, ResetPassword.ascx.cs

```
public partial class CMSWebParts_General_ResetPassword : CMSAbstractWebPart
{

    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

This is in the event log

Message: Could not load type 'CMSWebParts_General_ResetPassword'

Comment: What steps are you taking to create the web part?

Comment: I created a template and then created the web part. This works locally and my web part loads, however once deployed to the dev server, the web part stops working on dev.

Comment: @kallen you're going to have to provide more code behind OR more details about the setup and errors your receiving in order to provide some sort of solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately, Kentico seems to provide the most generic error possible, for something which could be caused by a simple syntax issue.

When I go to pages on the dev site of kentico and go to the new page and click design, I get this

Error loading the webpart 'ResetPassword' of type 'ResetPassword_1'

Comment: Has the code definitely compiled?  That error would suggest that the code behind `CMSWebParts_General_ResetPassword ` is not in the loaded assembly. (sorry if so, but I just wanted to be clear).

Comment: @mnield Im not 100% if it has compiled on the server correctly when publishing, but it has compiled locally and everything works fine on my local machine, I can get to the page and the web part loads. However, on dev I go to the same page and the web part doesn't load.

Dev is using the same kentico configuration as local, the only thing that could possibly wrong is something in the publish which has caused an inconsistency between the code and kentico.

Comment: @kallen, it may be that the compiled code did not get published to dev.  It sounds like you're using publish in visual studio, right?  Can you see the file system that you're publishing to?  If so, check `CMSApp.dll` in the `bin` folder and make sure it has updated and the file's date stamp matches your publish time.  It's sometimes possible that IIS has the file locked and does not let you overwrite it.  If that is the case, try and IIS reset and then republish or manyally copy the `CMSApp.dll` file into place.

Comment: @mnield I will double check the timestamp for sure, however Im not publishing from visual studio, this is a straight copy onto the server from my local machine of all files! I will double check the timestamp and get back to you :)

Comment: @mnield SO i think I found the issue, I havent been doing the deploys to the server, My freind has been doing the deploys and getting the latest version of the code - and then deploying through the file system. The timestamp on the server was different to mine so i got him to get latest and then build and clean and the dll has been recompiled, we are now deploying to the server again and hopefully this works.

Answer (score 4):

Have you created the code behind file as well?  I.e. `~/CMSWebParts/General/ResetPassword.ascx.cs`.  You'll need this too (and you may need to build it in Visual Studio if your project is a *web application* rather than a *web project*).

It sounds very much like the DLL does not contain the class for the web part code behind.  if you're sure that the code is compiling on your local environment, you should take a look at the way in which the deployment to your dev environment is taking place.  Ensure that the latest code has been pulled from your source control and that the solution has been correctly built prior to the files being deployed to the server.

If you're uncertain (in this instance of someone else doing the deployment), a good/quick way to check this is to look at the `bin\cmsapp.dll` and ensure that the date and time of the file reflects a recent update (i.e. likely to include your changes).

If your deployment is via file copy, you may wish to consider using some of the [publish options in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/not-in-toc/web-publish-options) going forward.

Comment: Hi yes, I have the code behind file created, just didn't paste the code due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed - The issue was the CMSApp.dll had not been compiled correctly.

For example, after a get latest version of the code through version control, if a deployment from the file system to the server is being done then you need to load the solution and build it to recompile the dll.

Redeploy and fixed!

Comment: OK, nice to know it's fixed and that it was that the code was not deployed.  Otherwise, it would end up being a more complex problem.  Given the conversation in the comments on your original question, do mind if I edit my answer to reflect the conversation and you mark it as correct?

Comment: Goo ahead! Your comment caused me to find my solution therefore you get the upvote!

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the answer to convey the detail in the comments from your question.